# Thread related problem while subscribing/using data

Tags: ros, threads

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been debugging my code recently and I've encountered this strange value assignments in my code (e.g. double value was set to 48342750631830156809646198744631837214400839096756594218130390397264833847717452548524106800103300384016854007123474855776033541556472495167585138333188621137621421726366230289867389262961030442796182455676615285992044974047232 ) for not exactly obvious reasons.

I then figured out that it could be thread related problem, where what I'm doing is writing and reading this variable at the same time which causes this strange assignments, but I'm not exactly sure.

I'will show you simplified idea of my problem. Lets say I have this main method:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "attitude_controller");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    attitude_controller_ = new AttitudeController(nh);

    ros::Rate rate(20.0);
    ros::Time previous_time = ros::Time::now();
    while(ros::ok()){
        ros::Duration time_difference = ros::Time::now() - previous_time;
        previous_time = ros::Time::now();

        attitude_controller_->control(time_difference);  

        ros::spinOnce();
        rate.sleep();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And I have **AttitudeController** class which has **FlyingStrategy** class in it that looks similar to this:

```
class FlyingStrategy {
public:
    FlyingStrategy(const ros::NodeHandle& nh);

    virtual ~FlyingStrategy();

    virtual void init();

    void control(const ros::Duration& time_difference);

    void callbackCarrotPose(const geometry_msgs::PoseConstPtr& carrot_pose);

private:
    virtual void pidControlLoop(const ros::Duration& time_difference, const tf::StampedTransform& transform_world_base);

protected:
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;

    ros::Subscriber sub_carrot_pose_;
    tf::Vector3 carrot_;
};
```

The main functions are here `callbackCarrotPose` and `control`. `callbackCarrotPose` is just assignment like this:

```
void FlyingStrategy::callbackCarrotPose(const geometry_msgs::PoseConstPtr& carrot_pose) {
    carrot_.setX(carrot_pose->position.x);
    carrot_.setY(carrot_pose->position.y);
    carrot_.setZ(carrot_pose->position.z);
}
```

The problem in my opinion occurs when I'm trying to set `carrot_` variable in `callbackCarrotPose` function and using this variable in `control` function at the same time. Because when I printed all the values coming to `callbackCarrotPose` function, all values were fine. But after printing them in `control` function sometimes the values were as show before.

How should I fix this issue then? Should I use some kind of thread lock in `callback` function and in my `control` function? And if so, how could I do it? I've not been using threads yet, so bear with me :).

Thank you for any advice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250457/thread-related-problem-while-subscribing/using-data/) by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 826 on 2016-12-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-20**:
Are you creating any threads in `FlyingStrategy` yourself? Because your `main` uses single-threaded eventqueue processing, so your callback cannot be called when `attitude_controller_->control(time_difference)` is executing.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2016-12-20**:
No, I'm not creating any threads by myself. But I have some classes that inherit from `FlyingStrategy` and there I use polymorphism. So I constantly change type of `FlyingStrategy`. Could it be the case perhaps? I can describe it more accurately if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So after a while me and my friend figured this out. It wasn't thread related problem at all. I had in my class `tf::Vector3`object which I initialized only after `callbackCarrotPose` was called. And because `tf::Vector3` has an empty constructor and it's member variable is some **array**, it never had any values before `callbackCarrotPose` was called, therefore those strange values occurred.

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2016-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0